# Allow to pass null values with DateTime.Parse(date.text) method in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, webforms, datetime-parsing

I have the following form:

[image]

---

once I click button Its working like this , all above parameters pass to `GetData` method

```
protected void btnShow_Click(object Sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ShowReport();
}
private void ShowReport()
{
     //Reset
     ReportViewer1.Reset();

      //DataSource
      DataTable dt = GetData(type.Text, category.Text,subsidary.Text,country.Text, DateTime.Parse(date.Text));
            ............................
}
```

this is `GetData` method

```
private DataTable GetData(string type, string category, string country, string subsidary, string dateHERE)
{
    // date = date.Value.ToOADate();

    DateTime? mydate = null;
    DateTime date2;
    bool check = DateTime.TryParse(dateHERE, out date2);
    if (check)
    {
        mydate = date2;
    }

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string connStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AB_ReportEntities"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    {

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("FindIncomplete_Products", cn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@type", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = type;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@category", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = category;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@country", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = country;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@subsidary", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = subsidary;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = mydate;

        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        adp.Fill(dt);
    }

    return dt;
}
```

I cannot get result when Date field has null values in above form , I'm getting the following error:

> System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: I think **date** parameter is an empty string.

Comment: use `DateTime.TryParse` instead and validate your inputs!

Comment: You might want to consider using [`DateTime.TryParse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Ric no method as TryParse once I try to add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your method like this:

```
private DataTable GetData(string type, string category, string country, string subsidary,string date)
{
     DateTime? mydate = null;
     DateTime date2;
     bool check = DateTime.TryParse(date, out date2);
     if (check)
     {
         mydate = date2;
     }
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
DataTable dt = GetData(type.Text, category.Text,subsidary.Text,country.Text, date.Text);
```

Comment: make your stored procedure parameters have defaults of NULL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89899/discussion-between-user2946329-and-kez).

Answer (score 2):

Obviously passing a value that cannot be parsed to a `DateTime` will throw an exception using `DateTime.Parse` so use `DateTime.TryParse` instead:

> The DateTime.TryParse(String, DateTime) method is similar to the DateTime.Parse(String) method, except that the TryParse(String, DateTime) method does not throw an exception if the conversion fails.

Source: [DateTime.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

example usage:

```
DateTime d2;
bool success = DateTime.TryParse(date.Text, out d2);
//if successful, d2 will be set to the value of the string.
```

Comment: getting this error `No overload for method 'TryParse' takes 1 arguments`

Comment: because it takes two arguments, the `string` value to convert and a `DateTime` object, will update my answer.

Comment: You need to pass more arguments. Read the documentation.

Comment: what Framework are you using? 4.0? this is the method from the metadata: public static bool TryParse(string s, out DateTime result);

Comment: @VJPPaz - 4.0, what is the problem? my example usage illustrates a string value and a date as an `out` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this extension:

```
public static DateTime? TryGetDateTime(this string item, IFormatProvider provider = null)
{
    if (provider == null) provider = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
    DateTime dt;
    bool success = DateTime.TryParse(item, provider, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
    if (success) return dt;
    return null;
}
```

Then change your method call in this way:

```
DataTable dt = GetData(type.Text, 
                       category.Text,
                       subsidary.Text,
                       country.Text, 
                       date.Text.TryGetDateTime());
```

Comment: `'string' does not contain a definition for 'TryGetDateTime' and no extension method 'TryGetDateTime' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` getting this error once I add this

Comment: @kez: it's an [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx). So you need to put it into a static class that is accessible from wherever you want to use it.